# Отправка сообщения спустя время после изменения статуса в кадровых изменениях Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

Необходимо отправлять сообщения пользователю через 7, 14, 21, 28 дней, после того, как в кадровых изменениях ему присвоят статус 'Штатный сотрудник'.

1. Как и где получать его статус, а точнее как настроить хук на выполнение операции именно после изменения статуса.
2. Как установить задержку и отправлять эти сообщения.

UPD:
Пример:

```
Поступил сотрудник. Ему завели учётку в Битрикс 24, статус "Сотрудник на испытательном сроке". После прохождения этого срока ему присваевается статус "Штатный сотрудник". Спустя 7 дней ему в живой ленте должно прийти сообщение "Важно! Вам нужно . . .". Спустя ещё 7 дней другое сообщение.
```

Comment: чтобы дополнить вопрос, используйте ссылку [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Выглядит так, будто бизнес-процессы в этом деле могут помочь. Они могут быть настроены на запуск после смены значения полей, но не уверен насчет уведомлений через N дней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, делюсь **решением**:

Всё смог сделать в самом редакторе Битрикса, без отдельного кода.

1. Редактировать нужно на самом сайте, а **НЕ** через админку.
2. Использование подобного скрипта в моём случае было привязано к определённому БП.
   Переходим: Главная - Автоматизация - Процессы - Выбираем нужный раздел БП *(В меню слева сверху - выпадающий список)*, выбираем нужный БП - Действия *(справа сверху)* - Настроить БП. Открывается страница шаблонов БП. - Выбираем имеющийся или создаём новый последовательный *(в моём случае)*.
3. Далее из конструктора выбираем **Пауза робота** *(из прочее)* ставим нужное значение.
   Добавляем под него Уведомление пользователя / Добавить новость *(в зависимости от нужного)*. Повторяем требуемое кол-во раз.
   Весьма удобный интерфейс конструктора условий. Для простых задач - самое то.

Спасибо всем, кто поучаствовал в этом вопросе.
Надеюсь в будущем этот ответ поможет и другим.

** БП - бизнес-процесс(-ы)